# signal() in C doesn't work

Tags: c, signals, fork

why this code doesn't work? I want that the code print the content of figlioA function if the number in input is even or print another code content in figlioB if the number in input is odd. What is wrong? Thank you!

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <signal.h>

int x;

void figlioA(int segnale) {
    if (segnale == SIGUSR1)
        printf("x=%d x^3=%d\n", x, (x * x * x));
}

void figlioB(int segnale) {
    if (segnale == SIGUSR2)
        printf("x=%d reciproco=1/%d\n", x, x);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int pidA, pidB;
    int a, b;
    x = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("Processo padre ppid=%d pid=%d\n", getppid(), getpid());

    pidA = fork();

    if (pidA == 0) { // figlio A
        printf("figlio A ppid=%d pid=%d\n", getppid(), getpid());
        a = getpid();
        signal(SIGUSR1, figlioA);
        pause();
    } else
        pidB = fork(); // crea il figlio B
    if (pidB == 0) // figlio B
    {
        printf("figlio B ppid=%d pid=%d\n", getppid(), getpid());
        b = getpid();
        signal(SIGUSR2, figlioB);
        pause();
    }
    if (pidA != 0 && pidB != 0) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            kill(a, SIGUSR1);
        }
        if (x % 2 != 0) {
            kill(b, SIGUSR2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which operating system? Looks like Linux! Then read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and notice that you should not call `printf` in signal handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug here:

```
if (pidA != 0 & pidB != 0) {
```

The correct should be "&&" and not "&":

```
if (pidA != 0 && pidB != 0) {
```

Edit: I got it working, for the kill function, As Chris Dodd said, you have to pass pidA and pidB, not a and b that are variables set in the child processes. You also need to initialize pidA and pidB to non-zero values, else process figlioA may enter in figlioB section after it have received the signal, you can also make the child processes return after `pause()`. Here is the correct code, i added sleep(1) to let the time to the childs to proceed:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int x;

void figlioA(int segnale) {
    if (segnale == SIGUSR1)
        printf("x=%d x^3=%d\n", x, (x * x * x));
}

void figlioB(int segnale) {
    if (segnale == SIGUSR2)
        printf("x=%d reciproco=1/%d\n", x, x);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int pidA=1, pidB=1;
    int a, b;
    x = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("Processo padre ppid=%d pid=%d\n", getppid(), getpid());

    pidA = fork();

    if (pidA == 0) { // figlio A
        printf("figlio A ppid=%d pid=%d\n", getppid(), getpid());
        a = getpid();

        signal(SIGUSR1, figlioA);
        pause();
        return 0;
    } else pidB = fork(); // crea il figlio B

    if (pidB == 0) // figlio B
    {
        printf("figlio B ppid=%d pid=%d\n", getppid(), getpid());
        b = getpid();
        signal(SIGUSR2, figlioB);
        pause();
        return 0;
    }


    sleep(1);
    if (pidA != 0 && pidB != 0) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            kill(pidA, SIGUSR1);
        }
        if (x % 2 != 0) {
            kill(pidB, SIGUSR2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I've fixed the code. When I insert an even number the program catch the signal but the code in the signal handler doesn't work. When I insert an odd number the signal handler don't work.

Comment: @AlessandroGuerra: you have no signal handler for odd numbers (SIGUSR2) -- you have two signal handlers for even numbers (SIGUSR1), the second of which will never do anything as it tests for SIGUSR2...

Comment: @ChrisDodd oh thank you! I changed the code in tests and I wrote bad. I've fixed the code but there is still the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with your code.  Besides the obvious typos (`&` instead of `&&`, `SIGUSR1` where you want `SIGUSR2`), you have a problem that you seem to want to set a variable in a child and use the value in the parent.  That won't work, as the child(ren) and parent have independent memory, so they each have their own private copy of all the variables.

So when the main parent (the one where `pidA != 0 && pidB != 0`) goes to send signals, it sends them to `a` and `b` -- variables that have never been set in that process -- so they might go just about anywhere.  You need to send the signals to `pidA` and `pidB` instead (if that is where you want them to go).

Comment: I've understand the problem. Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, I'm a beginner. I've tryed to send a signal with kill(pidA, SIGUSR1) but doesn't work.